# Low level implementation of web APIs

Tags: backend

I am learning the backend and I encountered the term API. But I was unable to understand its true nature in terms of programming like whats structures it really is made up of at its low level.

I watched several tutorials and articles but most of them were defining APIs as the interface between a client and server. Although from high level, this definition is good to understand but it's really confusing when it comes to its actual implementation. Because, initially I was thinking it as a unique type of entity itself, a new concept or construct which was mainly used in backend servers. But thinking more and more I realised that they also must be designed using the basic programming features like functions, classes and objects, modules, data structures etc.

So, I made some observations and want to know if these are correct or not.

> I think APIs are a fancy name for the high level functions of the web server which receives their parameters over the web from the client(since the web server is connected to the internet so it can do that). When it receives the request it evaluates them and based on their type or nature it calls for the particular function which is designed to handle that particular task like for GET request, for POST request, for DELETE request, etc. These function might be using an efficient data structure and algorithm to handle and process the request. But overall that's the APIs they are, a fancy name for the functions which are stored in web server.
> And the frameworks which provides an efficient and smooth way to create APIs like express.JS etc., hide these abstractions and complications to get the work done with these functions. They often implement these functions within an object or module, which only exposes the methods to process the particular request. I think, this is what we call the APIs, these server's functions which evaluates the request and process them accordingly.